# Creating a search engine of your site

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Am a student and novice to the domain of PHP (I have no idea on it). I have assigned a small task of creating a search engine of the website. (I have edited my code based on suggestions)

I have written the following code by searching the google and various forums.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.W3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> Results </title>
</head>

<body>

<center>
<h1 style="color:#09F; font-size:36px;"> Search </h1>
<form action="./results.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="input" size="50" value='<?php echo $_GET ['input'];?>' />
<input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
</center>


<hr/>

<?php

$input = $_GET['input'];
$terms = explode(" ", $input);
$query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";


$first = true;

foreach ($terms as $each) {
if ($first) {
   $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
   $first = false;
}
else {
   $query .= "OR keyword LIKE '%$each%' ";
}
}

//Connect to Database

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("databasem") or die ("database not found");


$query = mysql_query($query);



$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query) or die ("Here's the error");
if ($numrows > 0) {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$title = $row['title'];
$description = $row['description'];
$keywords = $row['keywords'];
$link = $row['link'];

echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>
$description<br/><br/>";

}

}

**else
echo "No result found for \"<b>$input</b>\"";**

//Disconnect 

mysql_close();

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Am getting the error in line where it is marked bold. mysql is showing that the query is wrong.

I searched google and I found the answers that PHP is using Mysqli instead of Mysql.

I have no idea on it. I found some materials and I was unable to understand it.

It seems to be a silly/useless question for you (experts) but as per my standards and experience this problem hurts me a lot.

---------------------------(Here Comes the points after updating the code)------------

After updating the code everything is going fine when searching but the last else Statement is not runnning. When we searches for the Name which is not located it is not displaying any results instead of displaying "No results found for $Input string".

Can anyone guide me over here please

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Can you post the output or error message ?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: I got that the SQL query is wrong at the line "keywords LIKE '%each%' ";

Comment: `"keywords LIKE '%each%'`. Looks like you might have dropped a $: `%$each%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main problems:

1) Bad variable:

```
$query .= "keywords LIKE '%each%' ";
                           ^---missing $
```

since there's no `$`, you're searching for the literal characters `e`, `a`, `c`, `h`.

2) Assuming your query can never fail:

```
$query = mysql_query($query);
                            ^---no error handling
```

You check for failure on connection and the num_rows call, but not on the most important part: the actual query. Try

```
$query = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

3) Vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

4) Using the obsolete/deprecated mysql_*() function library.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the foreach part, you never increment the $i, so it stays at 0.
This will make the query incorrect because it always picks the if part and not the else part

You also define the $i in the foreach so it will get created each time. It should be on the outside and on the inside of the loop should be $i++ (to increment the $i)

Syntax

```
$first = true;

foreach ($terms as $each) {
    if ($first) {
       $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
       $first = false;
    }
    else {
       $query .= "OR keyword LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }
}
```

Using mysql is deprecated in current versions of php so you should upgrade to mysqli or PDO where you can also use prepared statements for preventing sql injection.

But maybe that is not necessary for your school project

Comment: Could you kindly write the syntax over here please

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the fix and some tips

Comment: @MitchellOlsthoorn, This is a passable solution but maybe a boolean flag might make more sense and help readability? (e.g. `$first=true`, and inside the `if`, `$first=false`). The value of `$i` is meaningless after the first iteration.

Comment: @HPierce you're right. It should have cleaned it up a bit. I will update my anwser

Comment: @MitchellOlsthoorn: thanks for the code..

Comment: @Novice No problem. if it solved your problem, can you mark  it as answered

Comment: @MitchellOlsthoorn The else Statement is not running if the results doesn't match. When we searches for the Name which is not located it is not displaying any results instead of displaying "No results found for $Input string".

Can anyone guide me over here please

Comment: @Novice Could you echo the $numrows variable to see if it really returns 0 and also put {} around the else so formatting can't be the problem

Comment: @MitchellOlsthoorn Thanks for your quick turn around to my questions. I used $numrows, If it Displays the searched Content then it displaying "$" rows displayed if it doesn't find anything then it's not displaying anything about $numrows. Either 0 too..

Comment: @Novice The only way that the else could not be executed is when $numrows doesn't equal 0, so you should check if this is the case when there should be 0 returned rows